# Add-AzureRmServiceFabricNodeType -> 'accountName' cannot be null

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to use the 'Add-AzureRmServiceFabricNodeType' command to add a new nodeType to an existing service fabric cluster. This is my command:

```
Add-AzureRmServiceFabricNodeType -ResourceGroupName "$ResourceGroupName$" -Name "$ClusterName$" -NodeType "$TypeName$" -VmSku "Standard_H8" -Capacity 3 -VmUserName "$UserName$" -VmPassword $pwd
```

Having already logged in and set the subscription using 'Login-AzureRmAccount' and 'Set-AzureRmContext'

The call runs for ~1hr and then returns the following error:

> WARNING: Rolling back the changes to the cluster
>   Add-AzureRmServiceFabricNodeType : 'accountName' cannot be null.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-AzureRmServiceFabricNodeType -ResourceGroupName "%ResourceGroupName% ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureRmServiceFabricNodeType], ValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ServiceFabric.Commands.AddAzureRmServiceFabricNodeType

I have successfully added a nodetype to this cluster in the past, but then i didn't set the -VmSku option. As well as that difference, the subscription has since been upgraded from a pay as you go sub to an Enterprise Agreement. Based on the error received I guess it might have something to do with that, but i can't seem to find what exactly.

Any ideas?

Comment: 99% sure that the root cause is the upgrade from a pay as you go account to an EA account. The command that i ran previously (same as above, except without specifying vm type) returns the same error. It had completed successfully before the account upgrade.

Comment: As an update to this - the root cause is related to the way the cluster is setup with diagnostics enabled. The script fails when creating a new node and trying to config diagnostics for it. Debugging can helped by wrapping the command inside the following: `code`Start-Transcript
$DebugPreference = 'continue'  
COMMAND_HERE
Stop-Transcript`code`

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you used the secure encoding to provide the password

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Password$123456' -AsPlainText -Force
```

I also suggest you add the -Tier as part of your command, because as part of provisioning process it requires the sku, tier and capacity. If you not provide one it will use the default, and the sku might not be compatible with the default tier or your account availability.

You can also check in Azure if the VMSS are created once you run the command.
If you want to investigate further, I would recommend reading the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/preview/src/ResourceManager/ServiceFabric/Commands.ServiceFabric/Commands/AddAzureRmServiceFabricNodeType.cs) for the command operation executed for adding node types.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Diego - Yes the '$pwd' variable in my command was the secure encoded password. The -Tier doesn't seem to make any difference (From what i can see 'Standard' is the correct level for the vm type i use). No Vms are created with the command, but a load balancer is. I'm currently trying to get the source compiling locally as there is no obvious reference to the error i get. It's not proving easy to build locally unfortunately. Its complaining about '..\..\..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets.' not being available. 1.0.14 is though

Comment: I would recomend you checking 1) you have permissions with this subscription. 2) You can create VMSS from portal. 3) you can run other ordinary PS commands against your existing cluster.
Regarding the library, you should be able to get this package from nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Build